# How to handle null values in dynamic query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to manage dynamically null values in SQL Server procedure. I have prepared following demo, where assumed `@userid` is the input parameter of stored procedure

```
declare @userID  int =null
declare @suerid varchar(100)=@userid
select cast(@userID as nvarchar(100))

declare @sql nvarchar(2000)
set @sql ='select * from users where userid=isnull('+@suerid+',@suerid)'
print @sql 
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

When I pass valid integer value in `@userid` it gives desire output, but when I tried to pass `@userid=NULL` then it is not giving any output. I want 
to pass `@userid=NULL`.

Comment: Thats not valid at all, `@suerid` in the SQL string is out of scope of the `sp_executesql` statement and will error. `@userID ` is not in the SQL string at all and `isnull('+@suerid+',@suerid)` is meaningless ...

Comment: If You compare null to anything, then the result is always false. And @Alex has right. The given example is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first in in this line:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ISNULL(' + @suerid + ', @suerid)'
```

You will have a syntax error, because you have `@suerid` that is not declared inside of your `@sql`, So you should have this:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ' + ISNULL(@suerid, 0)
```

And if you want to return a row of `NULL`s when your input parameter is null I suggest you to use this syntax:

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT u.* ' +
           'FROM users u ' +
             'RIGHT JOIN ' +
                '(SELECT ' + ISNULL(@suerid, 'NULL') + ' AS ID) N ' +
             'ON u.userid = N.ID ' +
           'WHERE ISNULL(u.userid, -1) = ' + ISNULL(@suerid, '-1')
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what You want:

```
DECLARE @userID int
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000)
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM users WHERE ' + CASE WHEN @userID IS NULL THEN 'userid IS NULL' ELSE 'userid = @userId' END
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, '@userId int', @userID
```

**EDIT:**

If You get `NULL` as input, and want back all the users:

```
DECLARE @userID int
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000)
SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM users WHERE (userid = @userId or @userId is null)'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, '@userId int', @userID
```

**EDIT:**

Or even simplier:

```
DECLARE @userID int
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (userid = @userId or @userId is null)
```

Comment: This is a good point but I think there is not any null value in `userId` field when I think it is a PK ;).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a dynamic sql query? Dynamic sql is both [risky](https://xkcd.com/327/) and slow to perform, I suggest to avoid it whenever possible, even if it means writing more code.
If you must use dynamic sql, try this:

```
set @sql ='select * 
           from users 
           where userid = isnull('+ COALESCE(@suerid, 'null') +',@suerid)'
```

When concatenating a null value to a string, the entire string becomes null.